# Line Chart Series gets cut at top Sencha touch 2 charts

Tags: javascript, charts, sencha-touch, linechart

I am using line series in sencha chart. the issue is that markers with highest value in series gets cut at the top as shown in the image below. The blue line has a marker at value 1000 which gets cut at top in image.

This issue is also present in sencha charts guide examples in the documentation.

[image]

```
 {
               type: 'line',
               xField: 'name',
               yField: 'n1',
               itemId: 'incomeLineSeries',
               title: 'Income',
               getGutters: function() {
                  return [10, 10];
               },
               style: {
                  smooth: true,
                  stroke: '#63981a',
                  lineWidth: 3,
                  shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)',
                  shadowBlur: 10,
                  shadowOffsetX: 3,
                  shadowOffsetY: 3
               },
               highlightCfg: {
                  scale: 2
               },
               marker: {
                  type: 'circle',
                  stroke: '#0d1f96',
                  fill: '#63981a',
                  lineWidth: 2,
                  radius: 4,
                  shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)',
                  shadowBlur: 10,
                  shadowOffsetX: 3,
                  shadowOffsetY: 3,
                  fx: {
                     duration: 300
                  }
               }
            }
```

Any help about how to have some space so that the circular marker at top does not get cut ?

Comment: Might want to try setting a padding or height. Let me know if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add top padding to your chart: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.chart.CartesianChart-cfg-innerPadding

Comment: adding top padding worked like a charm !

innerPadding: {
            top: 5,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0
         },